# My page shows some other content in WP

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I have developed a `WP` site which is running in production [Nabby Studio](https://nabbystudio.com/). Here Under `Photography->Travel` the page is showing some other content while the URL is ok.

[image]

**Original**

[image]

I don't know what is the problem.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what do you see in the CMS/admin Panel for this particular page (travel-2).

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha same page as told in question

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha while customizing the theme I am able to see the original content

Comment: what do you mean by "same page". On you website, I see 2 pages. 


1- https://nabbystudio.com/travel/    - has correct content.
2- https://nabbystudio.com/travel-2/ - has wrong content

So what is the exact issue, are you adding some content to "travel-2" and not seeing that content on front-end? or what is the exact issue, please describe more

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha in `travel-2` I have added some images. Previously they were displaying but now they are not

Comment: Try adding them again, Also, to me it seems you are using the wrong page template

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha I tried to add them again but the same result. Moreover, images were displaying previously

Comment: May be, if I can have a look in the CMS I might be able to help. if you can share the credentials on direct message

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha i can't give you the credentials but I can give you access over TV or AnyDesk?

Comment: Whatever you prefer, I'm in a GMT +5.30 Time zone.

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha sorry for replying back late.. I am GMT +5:00

Comment: @Faizal, reach me in - https://www.linkedin.com/in/kasunrajapaksha/, stack does not allow personal messages to share credentials or anything like that